# Facebook Graph API /me/feed returning 302 response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to get FB.api /me/feed working, but it is returning a 302 Found status.

When a user has not allowed 'stream_publish' Extended Permissions the function works as intended, returning an error that the user has not authorized permissions for this action.

However, after accepting the Extended Permissions, and making the same call again, I get a 302 Found response from Facebook and a JS error pops up.

JS Error: syntax error - < !DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">

checking the NET response I see the call being made:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=[access_token]&callback=FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f32a1cd2d00c92&message=Reading%20JS%20SDK%20documentation&method=post&pretty=0&sdk=joey

and the returned status: 302 Found

Shouldn't the response be a 200 OK? What am I doing wrong here? Below is the code relevant to the problem... thanks a ton in advance!

P.S. It might be helpful to mention that OTHER FB.api calls such as /me and /me/permissions work just fine. Only FB.api /me/feed seems to be retuning a 302 Found.

```
<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="nowPost()">nowPost</a>
  <script>
    function nowPost() {
      var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
      FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
        } else {
          alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : fbAppId,
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth  : true
    });

    (function()
    {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/<c:out value="${locale}" />/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }()); 

</script>
```

---

**Update:** I noticed that other facebook apps using FB.api /user_id/feed/ were getting the same problem. Unless this is somehow connected to oAuth 2.0 (which I did upgrade our JS SDK to) I am inclined to think Facebook has broken something again.